# Devexpress winforms control rendermode

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0, devexpress

I was wondering how to set the `RenderMode` property of devexpress barmanager menubar control. I always see that when I use Windows XP style for default look and feel the menubar is always using `ManagedRenderMode` but I would like it to use `System` render mode. I using DevExpress library 9.2.9.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this helps but but please check out this ticket number [Q237247](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q237247.aspx) at the support center

All DX controls uses a LookAndFeel system to support skinning.  http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2534

You can disable the skins and enable Flat views and using XPTheme etc via the LookAndFeel property, this can be controlled globally via the DefaultLookAndFeel component available in your toolbox as well, please review http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2409

Hope this helps

Comment: Just linked the support center ticket as I have enough rep now to have more than 2 bloody url's :D

Comment: Nice one mate. Helped me to find out that DevExpress didn't care to add support for `System` RenderMode property. What a pain for developers.